# Show that $E_n =\{x \in \Omega : f_n(x) \ge (1- \epsilon) s(x)\}$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> (Tao Volume 2, P.196) $\Omega$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f_n : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function. $s$ is a simple function, which minorizes $f_n$. We fix $s$ and $\epsilon>0$. Let $E_n : = \{x \in \Omega : f_n(x) \ge (1- \epsilon) s(x)\}$. Show that $E_n$ is measurable.

Since $f_n$ is measurable $f^{-1}([a, \infty))$ is measurable for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. But I am not sure if $f^{-1}([(1- \epsilon) s(x), \infty))$ is measurable. Here, $s(x)$ in the interval bothers me. Is it okay to say $E_n$ is measurable? Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Won't $x\mapsto f_n(x)-(1-\epsilon)s(x)$ be measurable?

Answer (score 1):

Define a new function $F:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ by $F(x)=f_n(x)-(1-\varepsilon)s(x)$. This is a measurable function, as we know that $f_n$ and $s$ are measurable. It is simple to verify that $E_n= F^{-1}[0,\infty)$, which is measurable because $F$ is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For $0<c<1$, $f$ and $s$ real valued measurable functions

$$U:=\{x: f(x)<cs(x)\}=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}\{x:f(x)<q<cs(x)\}$$
where $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of rational numbers.

- For each
  $q\in\mathbb{Q}$,
  $$\{x:f(x)<q<cs(x)\}=\{x:f(x)<q\}\cap\{x: s(x)>q/c\}$$
  and so, $\{x:f(x)<q<cs(x)\}$ is measurable (for $f$ and $s$ are measurable).
- The set $U$ is the countable union of measurable sets.
- The set in your problem is $X\setminus U$.

See if you can put all this together. Notice that all you that is required is that $f$ and $s$ are real valued and measurable.

---

I am guessing form the notation in the OP, you are reading a proof about monotone convergence.